# How do I bind the same DataSource to two identical ListViews?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have identical ListViews in two different WPF Forms.  The first form opens the second one.  When I assign the same DataSet and DataTable as a DataSource to both ListViews only the first one updates when data in the DataTable is changed.  If I remove the DataSource assignment to the first Form ListView then the second Form ListView updates.

The Code for the assignment is,

```
WatchListListView.ItemsSource = MyProjectDataManager.myStockDataSet.Tables["InternalWatchListTable"].AsDataView();
```

MyProjectDataManager is a persistent C# class that contains and maintains my internal DataTables.

How do I get both ListViews to update?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a "real" answer, but I have more to say than can fit into a comment.

First, a point of order. You aren't binding to a DataTable, but rather to a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) of that table. That's not a bad thing as you *should* be able to create multiple DataViews of a table and have them keep in sync. That's kinda what they're for.

Second, to really help, we need more than the code you've provided. It'd help if we can compare the binding on the first ListView to confirm that they are, in fact, the same table. And it wouldn't hurt if we can see the actual code in your MyProjectDataManager, either (at least the relevant bits).

Things you can try to further debug:

1. Create a single DataView object and bind both ListView datasources to the same DataView. That should work fine as, again, DataViews are designed to handle multiple binding scenarios. It may be that your DataTable isn't notifying the secondary view of changes made, even though it really should.
2. Create a property accessor on your persistent data object just for that one table. I can't help thinking that your string accessor may be horked. That's not really likely, though, and I'm just expressing my latent dislike of strings in accessing table objects.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  “You aren't binding to a DataTable, but rather to a DataView” was the part I was missing.  By creating two DataViews, one for each ListView Both ListViews update when I modify data in the one DataTable.

WatchListDataView = myStockDataSet.Tables["InternalWatchListTable"].DefaultView;
                WatchListDataViewOne = myStockDataSet.Tables["InternalWatchListTable"].DefaultView;

Then in the two forms

WatchListListView.ItemsSource = MyProjectDataManager.WatchListDataView;

WatchListListView.ItemsSource = MyProjectDataManager.WatchListDataViewOne;

Comment: It remains a mystery to me why with one DataView for both ListViews only the first one updated and not the second.  If I close and then reopen the second form the ListView is updated.  But, the code is working the way I want it to now with two DataViews.  Thank you again.

Comment: I'm so glad that got you on the right track and you have it working.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide code to better understand while following steps may work but you may not like.
  1- Define a public function in 2nd form and bind your ListView inside it.
  2- After edit from 1st form call 2nd form public function where ListView will rebind -